# Not able to move class and Vf page in eclipes

Tags: eclipse, namespace

I am trying to move files from salesfore 1 env to another env. I am trying to move files using eclipse. I have created and namesapace in salesforce env from where i am trying to move files. so when trying to move the files it is getting an error that object name not found. i have moved all the object to salesfoce env where I need. Is there any way to get this resolved.

Comment: refresh once and get all metadata into eclipse and then retry

Comment: Can you post a stack trace of the error in question? If you have a namespace in one org but not the other, you may run into issues where your objects are trying to reference an object using the namespace as part of the name (and thus not finding it).